# WPF TextBox Mask to hide decimals if they are not there

Tags: textbox, wpf-controls

I am using a WPF TextBox editor to display a decimal value with 2 decimal places.

If i go into the TextBox, and put in the value 27.5, the textbox shows 27.50.

My current mask = "{}{double:5.2}".  Is there any way to hide the decimal places if there is no value there?  like 52 instead of 52.00?

Answer (score 0):

In C# and VB you simply make your format string `"0.##"`, so I would imagine you could do that/something similar in WPF.

**EDIT:**  You could also hook in to the TextChanged event and do something like:

```
TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
Double dblTemp = Convert.ToDouble(myTextBox.Text);
myTextBox.Text = dblTemp.ToString("0.##");
```

Comment: doing that actually makes the number 27.5 turn into 0.27 for some reason...  it doesn't seem to function like normal